# push Notifications for WordPress to Android app when new post is added on Wordpress?

Tags: android, wordpress

I want to send notifications to all the users who installed my app I am using firebase FCM to send notifications but from the firebase console I can send a notification but I couldn't send fro WordPress site when a new post is added.

Comment: It is not the WordPress based web site that is sending notification. It is your server. The server should notice a new post and trigger an event to send push notifications.

Comment: I need to find out from API that a new post is added to a WordPress site?

Comment: That would be one of the possible solutions. When a user sends a request with his new post data to the server it is accepted on the server somehow and then stored in DB. I suppose you can modify server part where it accepts new post data and stores in DB. After it is successfully stored - send a push notification. Everything related to sending notifications from server you can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server).

Comment: The Firebase Admin SDK, which has support for Node, Java, Python, C#, and Go 
and WordPress is on PHP may it does not support PHP and I am not good at backend part or server side?

Comment: Please provide some alternative solutions?

Comment: “*Please provide some alternative solutions*” That’s not how Stack Overflow works. This is not a coding or tutoring service. We are not here to tell you how to do your work, we are here to help you fix *specific* coding problems. **You are expected to have researched what you want to do and made attempts to do it yourself** before posting a question. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following two plugins to notify your users who have installed your application when you want a post to be published in your WordPress.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-push-notification-firebase/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pd-android-fcm/